# R: reading in file with unclear structure

Tags: r

I am trying to read in the file which is here [enter link description here](https://gammaray.nsstc.nasa.gov/batse/grb/catalog/4b/tables/4br_grossc.comments)

The first 15 lines describe the file but I don't want them. So I use skip=15.

Specifically, I use:

```
xx <- read.table(file = "4br_grossc.comments", skip=15)
```

I get the following:

```
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : line 1 did not have 12 elements
```

Any suggestions on how to handle this file? I expect it to have three fields (only) -- the trigger number, the one-letter code and the free-flowing text in the last field.

Many thanks!

Comment: Looks like a fixed width file - see `?read.fwf`

Comment: I am not sure that the last field has the same width always. Is it possible to leave the last width unspecified? If so, how?

Comment: Just make it an absurdly high number - looking at the source data it shouldn't be a problem to have very long strings.

Comment: Yes, it does work, but the last line is a mess. How do I skip the last line? I used: x <- read.fwf(file = "4br_grossc.comments", widths=c(4, 6, 100),skip=15)
Thanks!

Comment: I think `widths = c(6,6,100)` is required to read columns 1-2 correctly? Also I think the last line is as expected: the last record (and several others) are split over 2 lines. Those records have the same trigger number + flag, so could be 'stitched back together' in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
xx <- read.table(file = "4br_grossc.comments", skip=15, header=TRUE)
```

Comment: This does not work. I get: Error in read.table(file = "4br_grossc.comments", skip = 15, header = TRUE) : 
  more columns than column names

Comment: `read.table` uses white space as the default separator, so this will split the third field hence the error.